# how to fix message failed to extract packages during anaconda installation

Tags: anaconda, python-gui

I had installed anaconda. I have uninstalled through control panel and deleted the folder anaconda3 which was located on C:\users\HP\anaconda3.
During fresh installation it throws an error saying failed to extract packages. I have tried cleaning up C drive, removed temporary files, removed from system path, uninstalled python, pycharm, java, node.js. Checked in registry file no folder existing by name of anaconda. Please help in installing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What is the exact error message?  Is it simply "failed to extract packages" or is there more to it?

Comment: failed to extract packages. This was error message and it appears after approx 90% extraction.

Comment: Where are the packages extracting to? Don't assume it's the temp Folders. Is that location empty? Does Event Viewer show anything? Have you downloaded a new copy of the installer package?

Comment: Packages were extracting to C:\Users\HP\anaconda3. I dont know about event viewer. Yes I had downloaded fully ney installer package.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a bunch of posts of this without any great solutions. I had the error message about the failed package extracts on the latest version of Anaconda as of Oct 31, 2023. I tried "retry" a bunch of times, but it still failed. I also tried canceling and re-starting, but that didn't help either. One other user, @Borisl, suggested that the path might be too long. I am not able to change my path, so I don't have a lot of options.

I just ignored the error and continued on with the installation. I was still able to create new environment using the Anaconda Prompt for Spyder, and Spyder launched correctly and imported Pandas.

I think until Anaconda releases a new distribution or advice on how to deal with this, we can just keep calm and carry on.